# Template can't receive IList model

Tags: razor, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm writing an Umbraco application, and I need to send some Model to a page that inherits from the MasterPage like this:

```
@using ContentModels = App.Models.BlogPostViewModel
@inheritsUmbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage<IList<App.Models.BlogPostViewModel>>
@{
    Layout = "Master.cshtml";
}
```

But I'm getting the error:

> The type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList' must be convertible to 'Umbraco.Core.Models.IPublishedContent'

Here is the controller:

```
public ActionResult GetBlogsByMonthId(int monthId)
{
    var rootNode = Umbraco.TypedContentAtRoot().First();
    var blogs = BlogService.GetBlogsByMonthId(rootNode, monthId);
    return View("~/Views/BlogArchivePage.cshtml", blogs);
}
```

What is wrong? Should I make a new page altogheter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"IList" must derive from IPublishedContent to be able to use it with UmbracoTemplatePage. Instead, you can use UmbracoViewPage, which should work - see the code below :)

```
 @using ContentModels = App.Models.BlogPostViewModel
 @inheritsUmbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage<IList<App.Models.BlogPostViewModel>>
 @{
     Layout = "Master.cshtml";
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm getting the error `Cannot bind source type System.Collections.Generic.List [...] to model type Umbraco.Web.Models.RenderModel.` Am i missing something?

Comment: Try "@model" instead of "@inherits" :)

Answer (score 0):

Does your **BlogService.GetBlogsByMonthId(rootNode, monthId)** return an IPublishedContent List?   I was doing something similar:-

```
mainBlogPageContent.Children.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreateDate).Take(numberOfArticles).ToList()
```

and then passing it into my partial view as:-

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage<IList<IPublishedContent>>
```

I was forgetting to add 'ToList' - adding this fixed my problem.